# MacOS on MacBook Pro 2018 floods network while in sleep mode

Tags: networking, macos

This has been happening for a few weeks, but when my MacBook is in “standby mode” the traffic on our home network rises to such a high amount that no other network access is possible anymore. Seems to happen like a DDoS attack. And everything turns back to normal as soon as the MacBook is woken up from sleep.

It  happens on Wi-Fi as well as on Ethernet. When I turn off the device everything is fine. Also when I disable Wi-Fi or remove the Ethernet cable none of this happens.

I tried to capture the traffic on a different machine with Wireshark, but Wireshark does not record high traffic. Instead, it only records a packet each 2-3 second when this happens.

Turning off Power Nap and TimeMachine makes no difference.

I would appreciate any information of how to debug this.

Comment: If you turn it off rather than put it to sleep, does the issue persist? Wired or wireless?

Answer (score 1):

### macOS still does things in the background — including syncing things like Photos and Documents — while in Power Nap mode.

While Power Nap is a deeper sleep than a basic system sleep, it does not mean that macOS itself is not doing things in the background. [This list from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032) details everything that macOS is doing while in Power Nap mode.

> If your Mac supports Power Nap, these activities can occur while your Mac is asleep:
>
> - Mail receives new messages.
> - Contacts keep up to date with changes made on other devices.
> - Calendar receives new invitations and calendar updates.
> - Reminders keep up to date with changes made on other devices.
> - Notes keep up to date with changes made on other devices.
> - Documents stored in iCloud keep up to date with changes made on other devices.
> - Photo Stream keeps up to date with changes made on other devices.
> - Find My Mac updates the location of the Mac, so you can find it while it's asleep.
> - VPN on demand continues working so that your corporate email updates securely. (Power Nap supports VPN connections that use a certificate to authenticate, not VPN connections that require entering a password.)
> - Mobile Device Management can remotely lock and wipe your Mac.
>
> And these activities can occur while your Mac is asleep and plugged in to an AC power outlet:
>
> - Software updates download.
> - Mac App Store items (including software updates), download in the background.
> - Time Machine performs backups.
> - Spotlight performs indexing.
> - Help Center content updates.
> - Wireless base stations can wake your Mac using Wake on Wireless.

So my guess is some large files were recently added to your Photos or Documents — either on your Mac or perhaps another Mac connected to your account — and that is what is causing this spike in traffic.

My advice would be to check your Photos and Documents and — if all of the content is valid — then just let your MacBook sync the data and then the issue will naturally clear itself up.

Answer (score 1):

I am running a MacBook Pro 16" (2019) and it does exactly the same thing with 2 different USB-C to Ethernet devices (different manufacturers)

On my Win10 devices I just turn off "wake on lan", then device manager>Power Management> (uncheck) "allow this device to wake the computer" and the issue is gone - Apple, of course always has to make things difficult.

If anyone has a real fix please advise - thanks!

Comment: I've heard of this problem happening for other devices hooked up to USB-C hubs and docking stations too: https://superuser.com/a/1714510/220550 ; Sounds like it might be a more general problem with USB-C hubs/docks that aren't respecting some networking protocol and causing floods.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1118886)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with my brand new 2020 MacBook Pro, but it only happens after I plug the laptop back into my USB C hub (which includes network and power) after using it disconnected. After a few minutes it floods the network and no other device can access anything.

Oddly, if I go to the laptop and wake it from sleep by logging in it stops the problem and all other devices regain connection, and the problem does not happen again after it re-enters sleep.

So my workaround has been to be sure to log in to the laptop immediately after plugging it in to prevent the flood. Not ideal, but it has worked for me.