# Why does network traffic stop on one switch port, when the box on a different port is turned off?

Tags: networking

**Problem background**

I have a router that functions fine. I get about 100MB/s, this is bog standard TCP/IP that I feed into a Netgear 8-port Prosafe Gigabit switch.
The router output feeds into port 1 of the switch.

The switch is to share the network connection between two boxes, one MacOS and one Win10. (And others sometimes but let's go with the simplest case to demo the problem).

The Windows box plugs into switch port 2.
A small Dell Hub plugs into port 3.
The hub feeds into the Mac box.

**Hardware diagram**

```
router --> switch port 1
           switch port 2 --> RJ45 into a NIC in the Windows box
           switch port 3 --> RJ45 on Dell Hub --> Mac box via USB C
```

**Problem description**

This all works fine with everything connected and running.

The problem comes when I turn off the Mac. This means it is no longer consuming network traffic from the hub.
For some reason at this point the Windows machine stops receiving traffic, as if the switch has shut down. I can see the network lights on the RJ45 sockets and they look good, just that the other (Windows) box is cut off from the network until I unplug the hub, when it magically starts flowing again.

Why on earth does turning the Mac on switch port 3 OFF cause traffic to stop flowing out of switch port 2?
Why would the hub kill traffic coming out of the switch when it is no longer feeding out traffic?

More detail on the hub: The Dell hub is one of these small devices, a "USB-C Mobile adaptor". It is primarily a USB extender. It plugs into a USB-C port on the laptop, and has a collection of USB ports, an HDMI socket but also a single RJ45 port which is where the Mac plugs in.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not the only one:

https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/WD19-dock-kills-local-network-when-laptop-is-turned-off/td-p/7647346/page/2

Might be a bug in the hub/dock that triggers a broadcast storm that kills the network. One user found this to work after talking to Dell support:

> Dell Support asked me to disable Thunderbolt security and Wake on LAN, to see whether that fixes the Dock's packet storm issue.
>
> - BIOS > Settings > System Configuration > Thunderbolt Adapter Configuration
>   Change from User Authorization to No Security
> - BIOS > Settings > Power Management > Wake On LAN
>   Already set to (o) Disabled

However, other users have said that doesn't work for them. If the Macbook has an ethernet port, you might be able to wire it directly to the switch and bypass the problem. Otherwise, it might be time to try a different hub/dock.

Comment: Updating the firmware in the hub might also help. (But you may have to do that from Windows. I don't think I have ever seen Dell supply a MacOS version of anything.)